# MDX find last saturday 2 years ago

Tags: sql, mdx, dateadd, datepart

I am trying to write a statement that will return the comparable dates of last saturday one and two years ago. So if last Saturday  was 2018-01-06 I need it to return 2017-01-07 and 2016-01-09. The code below is returning 2017-01-07 (correct) and 2016-01-02 (incorrect).

See below code:

```
StrToMember("[Sales Period].[Sales Period].[Week Desc].&
        [" + Format(DateAdd("d", 
                                - DatePart("w", DateAdd("yyyy", -2, Now()), 1), 
                                  DateAdd("yyyy", -2, Now())), 
                                  "yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00") + 
        "]")
        --returns 2017-01-07        


StrToMember("[Sales Period].[Sales Period].[Week Desc].&
        [" + Format(DateAdd("d", 
                                 - DatePart("w", DateAdd("yyyy", -2, Now()), 1)-7, 
                                   DateAdd("yyyy", -2, Now())), 
                                   "yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00") + 
        "]")
       -- returns 2016-01-02
```

Any ideas of where there problem is? I get a feeling that I am overdoing it here.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you defining the comparable Saturday? Is is based on count, so you want first Saturday of previous years?

Comment: This question actually made me realize what was wrong. We define it as the saturday 52 weeks prior to last saturday. So last year is 52 weeks prior, and the year before that is 104 weeks prior. With that implemented it works! Thank you for the input!

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by using DateAdd("ww", -52, Now())) and DateAdd("ww", -104, Now())) as our definition of comparable Saturday is based on rolling 52 weeks, rather than 1 year.